# When socket timeout happens? (Unix)

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, timeout

When I connect to a Unix named socket, under which conditions I may receive ETIMEDOUT?

If it happens when the server does not accept() during N seconds, then what are typical N on Linux?

Comment: I doubt that you would even see this on `accept()`. You would see it on `send()` or `recv()` and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens if the server's operating system doesn't accept the connection within `N` seconds. The server application calling `accept()` is not normally relevant, because the operating system performs the 3-way handshake automatically, regardless of whether the application calls `accept()`; the TCP stack queues up the pending connections until the application does this (up to a backlog limit).

So normally this timeout only occurs if the server is physically down or there's a communication error on the network.

I think the default on Linux is 20 seconds.

Comment: Would you really see this on `accept()`? Surely TCP would just silently discard the incomplete connection?

Comment: The connection doesn't become available to `accept()` until after the stack has completed the 3-way handshake.